# How share data from rest service between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem consist in that I have some data in REST service and I want to get them and then send to rest of controllers. But I don't know how to do correctly because service $http.get() is perform asynchronously. I will show you piece of my code in order to better represent problem.

I created controller which is responslible for get data from REST service.

```
MyApp.controller("AppController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope,$http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/book").success(function(data) {
        $scope.bookList = data;
    });
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/author").success(function(data) {
        $scope.authorList = data;
    });
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/publisher").success(function(data) {
        $scope.publisherList = data;
   });

}]);
```

BookList, authorList, publisherList are building materials for rest of controllers.

Ok, I show other piece of code.

```
MyApp.service("BookListModel", function() {

this.createBookList = function(bookList, authorList, publisherList) {
    var i = 0, j = 0, authorName, publisherName, bookListItems = [];

    for(; i < bookList.length; i++) {

        for(; j < authorList.length; j++) {
            if(bookList[i].authorId == authorList[j].authorId) {
                authorName = authorList[j].name;
            }
        }

        j = 0;

        for(; j < publisherList.length; j++) {
            if(bookList[i].publisherId == publisherList[j].publisherId) {
                publisherName = publisherList[j].name;
            }
        }

        j = 0;

        bookListItems.push({'title' : bookList[i].title, 'author' : authorName, 'publisher' : publisherName});
        authorName = "", publisherName = "";
    }

    return bookListItems;
};
});
```

For example this is one of my serivces. It create book list with authors and publishers and it take three arguments and I don't know how pass data from AppController to createBookList function.

Comment: what is your problem? please elaborate more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a factory/service to make your REST calls (don't do it in a controller).

If you're making all these calls at the same time, you can use $q.all() to combine the promises and get a single promise.

Whenever a controller gets that promise, they'll get the same data each time and your REST services will only be called once.

Your controllers just call LibraryService.getLibraryData() and handle the promise to get the data itself.

```
MyApp.factory('LibraryService', function($http, $q){
    var service = {};
    var libraryDataPromise = $q.defer();

    $q.all({
        books: $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/book"),
        authors: $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/author"),
        publishers: $http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/publisher"),
    }).then(function(response){
        libraryDataPromise.resolve({
            bookList: response.books,
            authorList: response.authors,
            publisherList: response.publishers
        });
    });

    service.getLibraryData = function() {
      return libraryDataPromise.promise;    
    };

    return service;
});
```

Comment: This is maybe soultion of my problems but first I test it.

Comment: I've edited this a bit to clean up some bugs. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think that it is good solution for my problem but I have one objection. $http.get() not return objects fromm REST service, Propably I must use $http.get().success() but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The then() function is the same as the success() function. You can rename it in the example and it'll still work.
Ensure that the data you expect is in response.books (it might be response.books.data, maybe?).

From a controller, type: LibraryService.getLibraryData.success(function(data){console.log(data.bookList)});

Comment: correction: LibraryService.getLibraryData().success(function(data){console.log(data.bookList)});

Comment: Ok, now it's working. But my code looks little different: LibraryService.getLibraryData().then(function(result) {$scope.books = result.bookList.data}); Beacuse I'm not sure but result.bookList is response object with headers and data. But your soultion resolve my problem and I thank you for that!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do an angular broadcast. In your 'AppController':

```
....
http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/book").success(function(data) {
    $scope.$broadcast('bookList-updated', data);
}
....
```

Then in your other controllers where you want to use the data do this:

```
....
$scope.$on('booklist-updated', function(event, booklist){
    $scope.booklist = booklist;
});
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use angular services

```
app.service('mySharedService', function ($rootScope) {
    this.bookList = [];
    this.authorList = [];
    this.publisherList = [];

    this.setBookList = function (bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    };
    this.setPublisherList = function (publisherList ) {
        this.publisherList = publisherList ;
    };
    this.setAuthorList = function (authorList ) {
        this.authorList  = authorList ;
    };
    this.getBookList = function () {
        return this.bookList;
    };

    this.getPublisherList  = function () {
        return this.publisherList;
    };
    this.getAuthorList = function () {
        return this.authorList;
    };
});
```

Make sure to pass\inject your service to your controller

```
MyApp.controller("AppController", ["$scope", "$http", "mySharedService", function($scope,$http) {

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/book").success(function(data) {
    $scope.bookList = data;
    mySharedService.setBookList(data);
});
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/author").success(function(data) {
    $scope.authorList = data;
    mySharedService.setPublisherList(data);
});
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/library/publisher").success(function(data) {
    $scope.publisherList = data;
    mySharedService.setAuthorList(data);
});
}]);
```

NOTE: I didn't test the code.